# Recursive code for the computation of deciding voting blocks

Tags: python

Assume an election process with two sides, **"for"** and **"against"**.
I'm trying to write a program that takes a list of voting blocks as arguments and then computes how many times each block affects the outcome. For example, assuming that the argument `[1,2,3,4]` is passed, it should do the following.

1. Evaluate the possible combinations w/o 4, therefore the following:

   1. 1 + 2 + 3 (for) vs. 0 (against)
   2. 1 + 2 (for) vs. 3 (against)
   3. 1 + 3 (for) vs. 2 (against)
   4. 1 (for) vs. 2 + 3 (against)
   5. 2 + 3 (for) vs. 1 (against)
   6. 2 (for) vs. 1 + 3 (against)
   7. 3 (for) vs. 1 + 2 (against)
   8. 0 (for) vs. 1 + 2 + 3 (against)
2. The addition of **4** in cases 2-7 would cause the result to swing one way or the other (or tie). Therefore, the program would print that the last block (**4**) has the deciding vote in 6 cases.
3. Afterwards, it would do the same for voting block **3**, so the following would occur:

   1. 1 + 2 + 4 (for) vs. 0 (against)
   2. 1 + 2 (for) vs. 4 (against)
   3. 1 + 4 (for) vs. 2 (against)
   4. 1 (for) vs. 2 + 4 (against)
   5. 2 + 4 (for) vs. 1 (against)
   6. 2 (for) vs. 1 + 4 (against)
   7. 4 (for) vs. 1 + 2 (against)
   8. 0 (for) vs. 1 + 2 + 4 (against)

In cases 2,3,6 and 7 the addition of block **3** would change the result, therefore **3** is the deciding block in 4 cases.

4. And so on for **2** and **1**

I've come up with the following recursive code but for some reason it doesn't work for more than 3 blocks as arguments.

```
import math
def deciding_votes_per_block(blocks):
    if sum(blocks)%2: # same as last one
        return 1
    out = []
    for x in range(0,len(blocks),1): # going through each number in the blocks
        print(x)
        lst = blocks[:]
        del lst[x]
        out +=[swing_count(lst,blocks[x])] # sending out a list without element being checked for swing code as well as the element itself separately
    return out

def swing_count(lst_left, swing_vote, lst_right=[]):
    print(lst_left,swing_vote,lst_right)
    if not lst_left: # this in theory is compensated by next if statement
        return 0
    elif not lst_right: # where recursion starts because lst_right is defaulted to empty
        if swing_vote >= sum(lst_left): # if swing vote matters...
            return math.factorial(len(lst_left)) + swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]]) # return all possible arrangements of elements and shift first element of left list to the right list
        else: # if it doesn't
            return swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]]) # just shift first element of left list to the right list
    else: # if both lists are not empty
        if sum(lst_left)>sum(lst_right): # if left list is bigger we look if swing vote plus right list can overtake left list
            if (swing_vote + sum(lst_right)) >= sum(lst_left):
                return 2*math.factorial(len(lst_right)) * math.factorial(len(lst_left)) + swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]]) 
            else:
                return swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]])
        elif sum(lst_left)<sum(lst_right): # if right list is bigger we look if swing vote plus left list can overtake right list
            if (swing_vote + sum(lst_left))>= sum(lst_right):
                return 2*math.factorial(len(lst_right)) * math.factorial(len(lst_left)) + swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]]) 
            else:
                return swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]])
        else: # if sum of both lists is equal we get all possible arrangements of numbers and shift element from right list to left
            if swing_vote>0:
                return 2*math.factorial(len(lst_right)) * math.factorial(len(lst_left)) + swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]]) 
            else:
                return swing_count(lst_left[1:],swing_vote,lst_right+[lst_left[0]])
```

I've added some comments to make it kind of clearer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to work out the maths? From your example I can't see why all blocks would not have the same "swing count".

Comment: So this does not strictly speaking address your code, but might blow your mind or open a different implementation entirely. In your 1,2,3, 4 example, holding out for, consider (f^1+a^1)*(f^2+a^2)*(f^3+a^3). This is a^6+a^5f+a^4f^2+2a^3f^3+a^2f^4+af^5+f^6. Each term corresponds to one of your 8 scenarios in 1 (note there are two ways to the 3 to 3 tie). You can then do your analysis (basically has any position clinched, though the ties make it harder). For leaving out 3, you would expand (f^1+a^1)*(f^2+a^2)*(f^4+a^4). Wolfram alpha is happy to do that (or find a library that does polynomials).